# How to define a checkbox variable in Cakephp

Tags: cakephp

I have a form in my Plugin elements and what i would like to insert the checkbox value into a table named it_queries and field status_type and its giving me an error  Undefined variable: variableValue [APP\Plugin\Feedback\View\Elements\comment_add.ctp, line 37] .I have declared the variable in my controller like this

```
$this->set('variableValueStatus', 'Pending');
```

and this is line 37 thats giving me the error

Below is the Controller code

```
    App::uses('FeedbackAppController', 'Feedback.Controller');

class CommentsController extends FeedbackAppController
{
public $components = array('Feedback.Comments');

public function add($foreign_model = null, $foreign_id = null)
{
if (empty($foreign_model) ||
empty($foreign_id) ||
!$this->request->is('post')
)
{
foreach ($_POST['likebutton'] as $pageId => $likeFlag) {
$dbFlag = $likeFlag ? 'Yes' : 'No';
}
return $this->redirect('/');
}

App::uses($foreign_model, 'Model');
$Model = ClassRegistry::init($foreign_model);

if (!($Model instanceof Model))
{
return $this->redirect('/');
}

if ($Model->hasAny(array($Model->primaryKey => $foreign_id)) == false)
{
return $this->redirect('/');
}

if (!isset($this->request->data['Comment']['foreign_model']) ||
!isset($this->request->data['Comment']['foreign_id']) ||
$this->request->data['Comment']['foreign_model'] != $foreign_model ||
$this->request->data['Comment']['foreign_id'] != $foreign_id)
{
return $this->redirect('/');
}

$user_id = null;

if (isset($this->Auth))
{
$user_id = $this->Auth->user('id');
}

$this->request->data['Comment']['foreign_model'] = $Model->name;
$this->request->data['Comment']['foreign_id'] = $foreign_id;
$this->request->data['Comment']['user_id'] = $user_id;


$this->Comment->create();

if (!$this->Comment->save($this->request->data))
{
$this->set('validation_errors', $this->Comment->validationErrors);
return;
}

$this->redirect($this->request->referer().'#comment-'.$this->Comment->id);
}
}
```

and in the add view in my element here is how i am trying to accessing the variable value

```
echo $this->Form->checkbox('ItQuery.status_type', array('type' => 'hidden', 'value'=>$variableValueStatus));
```

If someone can show me how to fix this, that would be awesome

Comment: what type is your status_type field of? a String (varchar)?

Answer (score 0):

You are only passing the variable down on !post and if foreign model and foreign id are not set.
That will most likely not work in most of the cases.
You should be always passing down a variable if you do not check on it in the view prior to using it.

But it would still be wrong, anyway. You would have to use "default" instead of "value" if you dont want your form to fall back on the old value on POST (which it shouldnt).

Also, it is always better to use $this->request->data to properly fill the form with defaults:

```
if (!$this->request->is('post')) {
    $this->request->data['ItQuery']['status_type'] = 'Pending';
}
```

See [working-with-forms](http://www.dereuromark.de/2010/06/23/working-with-forms/)

Comment: even if i put this code in my controller its still not inserting the Pending into the table. Is there something that i need to be aware of?

Comment: Its not supposed to insert anything in any table. It just sets the default value for your form. Is that now working as expected? The part where you actually use the posted data and store it in the db you did omit in your code above and therefore I cannot give you any answers on that one.

Comment: i have edited my question and put in the whole Controller code....hope that will help me get assistance from you

Comment: this looks really really bad. you probably are quite new to Cake. but still, I havent seen this kind of code for a long time. Please take the time to make the tutorial and bake your code to see how its done right. It wass not only a wonder if it worked, nobody can understand your code either I am afraid. You can also take a look at http://www.dereuromark.de/2010/06/23/working-with-forms/ - some best practice approaches (although 1.3 style, the 2.x style is only slightly different).